# java stax get string of inner node

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am using java stax XMLStreamReader to read an xml.  I want to grab the whole string of certain inner nodes.

XML:

```
<example>
   <ignoreMe>
      <bla></bla>
   </ignoreMe>
   <getMe>
      <data></data>
   </getMe>
</example>
```

I just want to be able to get the whole internal getMe node in a String.  IE:

```
   <getMe>
      <data></data>
   </getMe>
```

Here is what I have.. but I am stuck:

```
XMLStreamReader parser = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(file)); 
for (int event = parser.next();  
event != XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT;
event = parser.next()) {

    switch (event) {
    case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
        if (parser.getLocalName().equals("GetMe")) {
             //??????????????????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started learning StaX last week, but if you are still looking for an answer to your problem, this may help you :

```
    XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    xmlif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);
    XMLStreamReader xmlsr;
    String resultat="";
    boolean isGetme=false;

    try {
        xmlsr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("lib/toto.xml"));
        int eventType;
        while (xmlsr.hasNext()) {
            eventType = xmlsr.next();
            switch (eventType) {
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                    if(xmlsr.getLocalName().equals("getMe")){
                        isGetme=true;
                    }
                    if(isGetme){
                        resultat+="<"+xmlsr.getLocalName()+">";
                    }
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                    if(isGetme){
                        resultat+=xmlsr.getText();
                    }
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                    if(xmlsr.getLocalName().equals("getMe")){
                        resultat+="</"+xmlsr.getLocalName()+">";
                        isGetme=false;
                    }
                    if(isGetme && !xmlsr.getLocalName().equals("getMe")){
                        resultat+="</"+xmlsr.getLocalName()+">";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(resultat);
```

This code will get you all the inner nodes and text contents, and store it into a String.
I.E:

```
<getMe>
      <data>test</data>
</getMe>
```

However, this code is quite "ugly" and is surely not the best solution for what you are looking for, JDOM may be more suited to your needs.

Comment: Thanks.. I ended up using JDOM.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/30298/1954)

check the method parser.getElementText()

HTH

This would get you the inner text, you may add the starting and ending name manually by a normal method. And since XML is a strict standard you're fine.

Comment: not really what I am looking for, my example xml is simple, but in reality it is complex and contains annotations to boot.  Plus the parser.getElementText() threw an exception for me.